# Highlight paths of a maximum distance between two points

Tags: qgis, python, network-analysis

I'm new to QGIS and very sorry if this is a simple question to ask.
Is there a way to highlight the available paths (roads) between two selected points in a road map?
I want to find the possible routes between two points in map, which less than or equal to a specified distance. For example, highlighting the roads(paths) between point A and point B which are less than 5km (if available).
And the two points are selected by the user on map, using mouse clicks.